# What are the "System Exclusions" in STAN4j and where do they come from?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have been analysing my code using [stan4j](http://stan4j.com) and it has been working fine, except it seems to ignore certain classes in the analysis for no apparent reason.

Inside System Exclusions there are tens of packages with classes that have been omitted in the analysis. I investigated them and couldn't find any pattern as to why they are being omitted, and what's worse, I can't find a way of forcing them to be included!

The stan4j documentation does not even mention System Exclusions, let alone suggest a way of dealing with them.

Does anyone have any idea for why this is happening? I can't analyse my code properly because of this!

[image: System Exclusions]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The free community license is limited to 500 classes. Classes above that limit appear under "System Exclusions". You may consider to buy a license or analyze smaller chunks of your code base...

Comment: I was unable to find where the licence can be acquired. Do you know how to obtain it?

Comment: I received an answer from the company behind Stan4j. They say the software is not supported anymore.